# Laravel - Send data from middleware to route

Tags: php, laravel, middleware

I am trying to send some data from the handle function in a middleware:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

class LanguageSwitcher
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (!Session::has('locale'))
         {
           Session::put('locale',Config::get('app.locale'));
        }
        App::setLocale(session('locale'));
        
        $locale = session('locale'); // => The data I want to send
        
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

My web.php:

```php
Route::group(['middleware'=>'language'], function () {
    // I want to set the prefix to locale here, but it's undefined
    Route::group(['prefix' => $locale], function () {

    });
});
```

I have tried to get the $locale in web.php using `Session::get('locale')` but I get Null.
So, is there any way to send it from the middleware to the route?

Comment: And ``App::getLocale()`` is set to the default value, so I cannot use it also!

Comment: you can use[ Laravel Localization](https://github.com/mcamara/laravel-localization) that handle all of this quietly.

Comment: one of the dirty solutions for your situation is: you can use `session('locale')` in your route.

Comment: All answers below are completely useless. The title has nothing to do with locale. When I search for this, I expect to find an answer to the question asked in the title. This is of course the fault of OP, not the answerers.

Answer (score 0):

i guest you want to use locale for support multi language. You can do with set locale in middleware and use the locale in your route. Here is my example https://pastebin.pl/view/c5034cb9